# Google Analytics : what is the difference between "Referral" default system channel" and "referral" medium?

Tags: google-analytics, channel, referrals

I'm learning the different features of Google Analytics and I have a question about the default channel groups. Especially, I am wondering what is the difference between the default system channel "Referral" and the medium "Referral"

According to [this page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3297892?hl=en), the default system channel "Referral" is defined by "Medium" exactly matches "referral". Unless I'm mistaken, I should get the same results if I use the medium or the system channel.

However, there are differences. Here is an example:

- In Acquistion > Overview, I have the results break by the default channel groups. For "Referral", I get 185 sessions
- When I use the "medium" as primary dimension, I get 205 sessions for "referral"

Could you please help me to understand this difference?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

this is happening mainly because of the Social channel grouping which rules are defined and executed before that of the Referral grouping. All visits from sites like facebook.com / referral, twitter.com / referral, t.co / referral, etc. are counted in the Social grouping. That's why you see more referral visits with medium as primary dimension.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it means that the real definition of Referral is
`Social Source Referral does not exactly match Yes
AND
Medium does not match regex ^(social|social-network|social-media|sm|social network|social media)$
AND
Medium exactly matches referral`

Comment: Just drill-down into the Social channel grouping and change the primary dimension to medium. If you don't use campaign tracking for your social media postings you'll see referral there.

Comment: You're right! How can I get the same "Referral" results than on the Acquisition > Overview page (that is to say the results with "Referral" treated as a default channel group, and not a medium). Thanks a lot!

Comment: The Acquisition - Audience report with primary dimension Top Channels should show exactly the same as Acquisition - Channels

Comment: Yes, these views are identical. Do you know how I can get these results with the API? (for testing purpose, I'm using the API Explorer : https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/analytics/v3/) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried the Channel Grouping dimension:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=channel_grouping ?